# Will lenses with filter attachment size 58mm fit my camera when the kit lens has filter size 72 mm?

Tags: lens-mount

I need help - I want to buy 50mm f/1.8 for my Nikon d300.  The description of the lens says Filter Attachment Size 58mm.  My kit lens is filter size 72 mm.  Is 58mm is the right size lens for my camera or do I need any extra rings?

Comment: Does my edit accurately reflect your meaning, or are you actually asking if the same filters will fit both lenses?

Answer (score 5):

Don't worry. That size is for attaching filters (for example, polarizing or colored) to the *front* of the lens. The lens mount, on the *back* side, is standardized and is the same for all Nikon F-mount lenses (which your camera uses).

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, the OP has a kit lens with a filter thread size of 72mm, and a 50mm f/1.8 lens with a filter thread size of 58mm. That would be two different *filter* sizes, not the difference between the filter mount and the lens mount...so wouldn't an adapter ring be required?

Comment: I _think_ that the questionner is trying to determine if the _lens_ will fit the camera, and is worried that it won't because of the filter size marking. I don't think the question is actually about filters at all.

Comment: And in that case, a filter ring certainly would _not_ be required to just mount the 50mm lens.

Answer (score 2):

You can use your 72mm filters in your 50mm f/1.8. You will need a ring adapter 58 » 72 to use the same filters